# Notificaciones en Woocommerce: Notificar a distinto email de la transacción dependiendo de cliente

Tags: php, woocommerce

Hace poco comencé con Woocommerce. Hice una pequeña web interna donde los clientes registrados (que son seis) eligen productos y luego hacen el checkout. De estos seis clientes, tres responden a una persona y otros tres a otra, por tanto me pidieron que cuando 3 compren llegue un email de notificación a un proveedor y cuando los otros compren a otro.

**¿Dónde podría agregar eso y poner una condición en el envío de notificaciones por compra?**

Lo principal es que estos 6 clientes son fijos, por lo que podría identificarlos por sus correos.
Para que no queden dudas explico con un ejemplo:

*Si tengo 6 clientes. 1@mail.cl, 2@mail.cl, etc.. Cuando los primeros 3 compren algo la notificación debería llegar a notificación1@mail.cl y cuando compren los otros 3 la notificación debería llegar a notificacion2@mail.cl*

Me imagino que debo modificar algún php del plugin, alguna ayuda? 
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Aquí tienes un ejemplo: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83429/how-to-choose-email-recipient-in-contact-form-7-based-on-address-state-input-in

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, pero no entiendo el ejemplo ya que habla de contact form. Me imagino debo cambiar los datos dentro del php de contact form para que genere esa acción.

Comment: El ejemplo que muestro es para Contact Form 7 de Wordpress, si no tienes ese, deberías especificar cuál es el que usas tu.

Comment: El plug in Woocommerce automáticamente con la compra envía un mail de notificación (que se agrega en su configuración) . el problema es que solo se pueden sumar pero no permite derivar de acuerdo a tipo de pedido u otros datos

Comment: Entiendo, se hace distinto, pero al igual que con Contact Form, Woocommerce tiene ganchos para todas sus funciones, aquí un ejemplo: https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-emails/ se trataría entonces de localizar la función que te interesa y reescribirla por medio de su hook para que haga lo que tu quieras.

Answer (score 0):

Al final encontré una posible solución:
Ingreso este código en el functions.php de wordpress:

```
    function custom_use_customer_from_address ( $from_email, $obj ) {
        if ( is_a( $obj, 'WC_Email_New_Order' ) ) {
            $address_details = $obj->object->get_address( 'billing' );
            if ( isset( $address_details['email'] ) && '' != $address_details['email'] ) {
                $from_email = $address_details['email'];
            }
        }
        return $from_email;
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_from_address', 'custom_use_customer_from_address', null, 2 );

    function custom_use_customer_from_name ( $from_name, $obj ) {
        if ( is_a( $obj, 'WC_Email_New_Order' ) ) {
            $address_details = $obj->object->get_address( 'billing' );
            if ( isset( $address_details['first_name'] ) && '' != $address_details['first_name'] ) {
                $from_name = $address_details['first_name'];
            }
            if ( isset( $address_details['last_name'] ) && '' != $address_details['last_name'] ) {
                $from_name .= ' ' . $address_details['last_name'];
            }
        }
        return $from_name;
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_from_name', 'custom_use_customer_from_name', null,2);
```

y luego el origen y asunto de las notificaciones de Woocommerce a mi mail ya no serán por número de compra sino por mail de usuario. De esta manera lo único que debo hacer es crear reglas en mi buzón de entrada que derive los correos que yo desee a x proveedor y los otros a y proveedor.